# Symfony course application setup question

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

Hello i got a question about how to setup my project the best way.

In the application people can start a course, a course takes 4 weeks and every week there are tasks you should complete.

The idea is a course can be made within the application, so you can add weeks and tasks and make a course.

Next a user can start a course on any given moment. When a user start the tasks will have a status and people can comment on there work.

So the course someone made should somehow be copied for the specific user so the user specific data can be saved with the tasks.

Why i think this should be copied is because the course can change over time and you don't want that people that are already doing the course or finished it get changes in it.

The only thing i can think of is make all entities twice, one for makes the course and one for users running the course with some extra fields.

Is this the best way in symfony? or is there a better setup?

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective you need to have these entitites:

User > Course > Tasks

Course has a oneToMany field to Tasks, that implement the week.

If a course changes, you just create a new one (or set a canonical_name) and set a status (to make it invisible). Current subscribed users won't notice changes and the new ones see the new.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
But the changes on a course will be that the course evolves and get better over time where tasks will changes / extended or be removed from an existing course. When new people start the course they get the course in state it is in at the moment.

So people that did the same course a year ago can be different from the course now but should still be the same course.